# Div position:fixed works wrong on small screens

Tags: css, css-position

please look at these two pictures:

1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0QlP.png

2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPgZb.png

On the first picture I have my gallery menu on proper position. All four buttons are part of div "fixedmenu". Below I have that darker container, which I called "menucontainer". When you look on the second picture you can easily understand my problem - I can't set my menu only on darker div, but it's fixed no matter what screen size is used. Code looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="menucontainer">
       <div id="fixedmenu"> buttons are here </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

my css looks like this:

```
#menucontainer{
   width: 200px;
   height: inherit;
   float: left;
   left: 0;
   background-color: #313131;
}

#fixedmenu{
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 200px;
}
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Big thanks for help.

Comment: You can add `z-index` and `top:0;` to fixed div plus you need to reduce width of the content container.

Comment: but z-index won't keep that div on darker part on the left, right?

Answer (score 0):

you try like this

Add css:

```
#menucontainer{
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   width: 200px;
   height: inherit;
   float: left;
   left: 0;
   background-color: #313131;
}
```

Comment: still the same problem